# How to format C# with Rider through command line?

Tags: c#, terminal, formatting, rider

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html) it's possible to do something like:

```
idea64.exe format -r -m *.cs .
```

..from the root of your solution. But I don't have the full InelliJ Idea, I have Rider. When I run:

```
rider64.exe format -r -m *.cs .
```

Nothing really happens, no output in the console and no files formatted. In `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2020.3.2\bin` I found `format.bat` and `rider.bat`, and I tried various combinations of using that, but then I only get a bunch of java related errors in the console and no code formatting.

Is there a way to format / cleanup the code using Rider and `.editorconfig` through the command line somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't really a function of Rider, at least not that I'm aware of.

You could try [CleanupCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/CleanupCode.html) which is free and cross-platform. Otherwise, you could always implement something like [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop).